# Community should cause correc! Ou : Community pris en flagrant délit d'idéalisme... ;-)

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

Et recel d'idéalisme + incitation au jugement de valeur... ;-)

Horresco referens!

Yo! Malgré l'accroche provo pour le plaisir et la galerie... ceci n'est que broutilles mais comme j'ai bien noté qu'il s'agissait d'un banal programme, ma requête devrait être facile à implémenter...

Je viens de lire un message de *community* *bumpé* dans le cadre d'une question posée sur FSE :

*"This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed"*

Relativement à des questions sur la langue, je ne suis pas partisan de considérer (ou de suggérer l'idée) qu'il puisse exister des *bonnes* réponses et des *mauvaises*... à ce train là... il manque *evil* et le compte y sera.
La suite de la phrase prête aussi à conséquence dans la mesure où elle invite la communauté à prononcer ce jugement de valeur dans le cadre de la revue, voire suggère que la revue consiste dans le prononcé d'un jugement de valeur.

Je voterai donc pour, dans la mesure du possible, à l'occase d'une Vn+1, changer *good or bad* pour ***correct or not***

Nota : Ce message, pour s'afficher en anglais sur mon écran est peut-être standard pour tous les xyztSE... je crois pouvoir affirmer que tout anglo-saxon honnête me suivrait dans ce sens, le jugement de valeur ayant de nos jours assez mauvaise presse *worldwide*.

---

[English summary: in the message *"This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed"* when a question with only zero-score answers is bumped, I am against describing answers as “good” or “bad”: why not “evil” while we're at it? This and the rest of the sentence suggest a value judgement. I move that “good or bad” should be changed to “correct or not”.]

Answer (score 6):

[English summary: I disagree.]

Je ne suis pas du tout d'accord. Les années passées sur Stack Exchange m'ont très amplement montré qu'il y a des bonnes et des mauvaises questions, et il y a des bonnes et des mauvaises réponses. En anglais comme en français, « *good*/bonne » et « *bad*/mauvaise » sont des jugements de qualité, pas de morale.

La qualité d'une réponse va bien au-delà de sa correction. Une réponse peut être bonne malgré quelques erreurs qui la rendent pas complètement correcte. Réciproquement, une réponse peut être correcte mais mauvaise, par exemple parce qu'elle est est quasiment incompréhensible, ou parce qu'elle manque d'explications.
Par exemple, pour une question du type « comment exprimer ce concept en français », une réponse qui propose plusieurs mots et explique dans quels contextes les utiliser, mais orthographie mal ces mots, est incorrecte mais néanmoins utile, et ne demande qu'à être un peu améliorée. Réciproquement, une réponse qui consiste juste en « [mot]. 30 caractères......... »¹ est peut-être techniquement correcte, mais sans intérêt.

Concrètement, dans le contexte du message « *This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed* » si une réponse est bonne, le bon comportement est de la plussoyer (*vote up*). Si elle est utile dans l'ensemble mais a quelques défauts, le bon comportement est de l'éditer pour corriger ces défauts mineurs et de la plussoyer. Par contre, si une réponse est techniquement correcte mais médiocre, il n'y a pas lieu de la plussoyer. Si elle est complètement inutile, le bon comportement est de la moinssoyer ou de l'effacer. Bien sûr, si aucune des réponses n'est satisfaisante et que vous en êtes capables, vous êtes encouragés à en écrire une.

Quand aux revues, ce sont bel et bien des jugements de valeur. Il s'agit de juger la qualité d'une réponse, pas sa morale. C'est la [valeur](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/valeur) au sens IV, pas au sens III ou V.B.

---

Comme tu le soupçonnes, ce message est commun à tout le réseau Stack Exchange. Pour qu'il y ait la moindre chance de le modifier, il faudrait une discussion sur [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) (en anglais). Comme je ne suis pas d'accord avec ta proposition, je ne m'en ferai pas le relai.

¹  <sub>Je n'ai jamais vu ce genre de remplissage pour atteindre la longueur minimale d'une réponse ici, mais sur [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), si.</sub>